# unable to get complete content of parent div using .html() functions limitations

Tags: jquery, html, jspdf

I am trying to get content of a div using .html() function but it not returning complete content. I have approx 28 divs and all of them have huge data. When I am trying to use .html() jquery function it is returning only 18 divs. If there any other alternative for this?

```
$('#parentDiv').html()
```

P.S. I want this data to be saved in pdf for that i am using jspdf plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing all the relevant code we can't really help you. Are you sure all the `div` elements exist in the DOM when you make this call?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this solution, this will resolve your problem**

```
/* get count of number of child div */
var count = $("#parentDiv").children().length;
var htmlContent = "";

/* Read html of each child div */
for (var i=0; i< count; i++) {
    htmlContent += $("parentDiv:nth-child("+i+")");
}
```